# Identifying the input_shape in Dense model - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset of 462 samples and 11 features. This makes the shape of my dataset (462,11). When I split the data using train/test split, the shape of my X_train is (231,11). I'm confused on what the input_shape in the Dense model would be? Would making it (231, 11)be correct? I have shown this below in code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X,y, test_size = 0.5, random_state=45)
print(X_train.shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_shape= (462,11), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(Dense(500, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'linaer'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes in the last dimension of the input only where the input is of shape `(batch_size, units)`. With that in mind do not **hardcode** the exact input shape which can be taken from the last dimension of `X_train`.

```
model.add(Dense(500, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), activation = 'relu'))
```